# How do you change the color of multiple shape layers at once in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, layers, mask

I have a series of shape layers that I am using to create a logo.

These shape layers are not directly above or below each other. Instead, they are spaced out between a series of other shape layers. I can't move these layers, nor can I move the layers above or below them (because the design's structure won't let me do that).

**How do I change the color of multiple layers (shape/vector layers) at the same time?**

I can change the colors individually but it's such a tedious task, and with clients asking for color changes constantly, I was wondering if there was a quicker way.

[image: This is what my layers look like]

Comment: We have [**a similar question here**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21591/change-the-color-of-multiple-layers-at-once?rq=1), but for CS4. Might be of help, though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Select the Shape Layers by Pressing `CTR` key
2. Select any Shape Tool from tools palette
3. Choose Shape from option palette
4. Choose color from option palette you want to put in all selected shape layers

This will surely work

For more help see [this Video](http://youtu.be/qaxaiy1yAtg) 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to change the color of multiple shapes (in separate layers), I would do it the following way:

1. *Right Click* on One of the layers and select **Blending Options...**
2. On the left, check the box that says **Color Overlay**
3. **Change the color** to whatever you want
4. **Exit** out of *Blending Options*
5. Right-Click the layer and select **Copy Layer Style**
6. Shift-Select the *all* the layers you want to change the color of *(I think you can even select folders)*
7. Right-Click and select **Paste Layer Style**
   Hopefully this achieves what you wanted.

Comment: omg this answer saved my life

Answer (score 1):

Hey wherepixelscometodie, the two other options do work, but with this one you don't have double color options (layer style) and you can copy all attributes, including the border.

1. Edit **one shape** the way you want to have it
2. right click on it and select "**Copy Shape Attributes**"
3. select all layers you want to change (w. cmd+click)
4. right click on one of them and select "**Paste Shape Attributes**"

Answer (score 0):

method 1 for cs6

1)**Select each shape layer**, then select a shape tool (Rectangle tool, ellipse tool, etc.) **In the Options bar at the top, there is a dropdown for fill and stroke.** If you have each shape layer selected by pressing ctrl or cmd, **change the fill** and it will change all of them. If you're using the eyedropper from there, you won't see the colors change until you click "OK".

Method 2

1) You can change "colour overlay" in "blending options" of a shape, than "copy layer style" of the shape, select shapes you need to change and "paste layer style"

2) Select shapes and make a "smart object". Now you can work with it like you work with a simple layer. You can edit smart object by choosing "edit content" menu