# Color Mapping in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, workflow, website-templates, swatches

I am making web templates and am looking for a quick way to change color schemes efficiently. I need to map different items to a certain color/swatch and change all of those items linked to that color to a new color.

ex. Nav bar background, footer background, and text link color are all #333333 and for the new color scheme, they all need to change to #444444.

**Similar to character or paragraph styles in InDesign**

Comment: See similar question [How do you change the color of multiple shape layers at once in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30660/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-multiple-shape-layers-at-once-in-photoshop)

Comment: nope. not it. I am looking for something to change everything that is a certain color (shapes and text). and not have to go searching through the mess of a .psd that i am given or searching through and command clicking all of them. *Like paragraph/character styles in InDesign.

Comment: You could use smart objects for shapes and **Photoshop has paragraph/character styles** So.. errr... yeah... not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: hmmm... i am still trying to figure out how to phrase this workflow. I am trying to change every instance of a single color to a new single color. Lets say I have a primary color of #333333 that is used for multiple different layers (multiple shapes, text). For my new color scheme, I need to change all of the things that were colored #333333 to #444444. It is a pain to find all of the layers that are colored #333333 in the layers panel, and when I do find them, they need to be changed two different ways.

Comment: As I was writing that, I began to understand what you meant by the smart object as the shape layer. That isn't exactly what I had in mind, but will definitely cut down on the steps. Thank you!

Comment: I can envision now what your'e thinking... like global swatches in Illustrator - change the swatch and *everything* with that swatch applied changes. Photoshop, just doesn't have that capacity as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Scott, you are the man! That is totally what I am asking. I actually found this plugin that solves this problem. [PRISMA Extension](http://www.codeadventure.com/)

Comment: That does appear interesting Jordan :)